# How to make everything dark beside one DOM element?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to make the screen pretty dark via CSS beside one DOM element and it's children

How do I do that?

**EDIT**: I want to do something similar to chrome's dev tools 'inspect element' UI

Comment: some code perhaps? Or an image of what you are after? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` layer on top of the whole viewport. Give it some transparency or simply a solid background colour. Raise the element you want to be on top of that layer using CSS `z-index`.

As @jfriend00 pointed out, you first need to change `position` of your element to `absolute` or `relative`. Then, you have to position the element again using `left` and `top` (for example).

Comment: `z-index` only affects an element if it is positioned (like position: absolute) so this solution is more involved than you have described.  One can't just add `z-index` to an element that is in the normal layout of the page and expect it to pop to the top.  `z-index` rules described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index.